# Trying to get two buttons drawn on top of each other

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I;m trying to have a top button and a buttom button.  But only the buttom button gets drawn.
Here is the code

```
    add(panel1,BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    add(panel2,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

the complete function

```
private void initUI() {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  set upui
    setTitle("Simple example");

    // Set size to match screen
    mWidth=(int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()-50;
    mHeight=(int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()-50;
    setSize( mWidth, mHeight);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    // Set close operation to exit
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JPanel panel1 =new JPanel();
    JButton btn = new JButton("Top Button"); // Button is a Component
    btn.addActionListener(this);
    panel1.add(btn); 

    JPanel panel2 =new JPanel();
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("Buttom Button"); // Button is a Component
    panel2.add(btn2); 

    add(panel1,BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    add(panel2,BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    // Add the chart
    // NOTE class DrawCompoment is defifin below where the drawing ooeration is overidden
    DrawComponent test = new DrawComponent();
    add(test,BorderLayout.CENTER);  

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // sert up vscreen
    vStartX=(double)10;  
    vStartY=10;
    vWidth=mWidth-40;
    vHeight=mHeight-80;

    dx=vWidth/t.daySize;
    dy=vHeight/t.dayBiggest;

    // save fdata in spreads sheet
    createSpreadSheet();


}
```

Comment: "Trying to get two buttons drawn on top of each other" I'm assuming one would only show up if you follow that logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding panel1 and panel2 both to the same BorderLayout position, and only one can be added there. You need perhaps another JPanel to hold them both and then add that one to the BorderLayout.NORTH spot.

e.g.,

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JButton btn = new JButton("Top Button"); // Button is a Component
btn.addActionListener(this);
panel1.add(btn);

JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JButton btn2 = new JButton("Buttom Button"); // Button is a Component
panel2.add(btn2);

// A JPanel to hold both panel1 and panel2
JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
containerPanel.add(panel1);
containerPanel.add(panel2);

// add only one component to the BorderLayout.NORTH position of the JFrame
add(containerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Didn't you question me about answering a similar question a few days ago, instead of marking it a duplicate ;) (no offensive ;))

Comment: @MadProgrammer: sigh, guilty as charged. Goose/gander and all that.

Comment: Seriously, don't sweat it ;)